# error in (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.cucumber.gherkin.GherkinDocumentBuilder.<init>(io.cucumber.messages.IdGenerator, java.lang.String))

Tags: selenium, maven, cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x78pW.png)

```
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void io.cucumber.gherkin.GherkinDocumentBuilder.<init>(io.cucumber.messages.IdGenerator, java.lang.String)'
```

> I'm getting this above error i have tried everything by using google
> im in learning stage can you guys help me and image is attached

Comment: It looks like your dependencies are inconsistent. Try starting over with the https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

If you use maven, add this `dependency`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/gherkin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That doesn't look right. This is a very old Gherkin version.

Comment: Add the latest version according to your setup (updated the answer), as i can not see the complete errors logs, so i tried to provide you the most efficient and reliable  feedback here

Comment: I'm not the person asking the question. :D

Comment: Thanks, this will help to the person who asked the question